# How do I upgrade PHP 5.1 to 5.2 on SUSE 10.1 using the yast command line only?

Tags: php, linux, command-line, opensuse, package-managers

How do I upgrade PHP 5.1 to 5.2 from the SUSE 10.1 command line?  Is there a package manager command to do it automatically?

Actually I need JSON support to use the JavaScript-RTE and believe it's in PHP 5.2 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [zypper](http://en.opensuse.org/Zypper)?

I got this, already having latest available.

```
aansari:~ # zypper in php
Downloading repository 'openSUSE-11.0-Updates' metadata [done]
Building repository 'openSUSE-11.0-Updates' cache [done]
Reading installed packages...
'php5' providing 'php' is already installed.
Nothing to do.
aansari:~ #
```